# Observable with Async pipe not working inside *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a base component called `base.component.ts` where I fetch data from an `HTTP Endpoint` and pass it to another `Component` called `ListView`.

**base.component.html**

```html
<ng-container>
   <list-view [dataSet]="data" [isLoading]="isLoading"></list-view>
<ng-container>
```

**base.component.ts**

```js
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {

   // Keeping data as a Subject. Ignore any type I added to make it simple
   data: Subject<any> = new Subject();

   // Keeping a loading state.
   isLoading: BehaviourSubject<boolean> = new BehaviourSubject( false );
   

   // Injecting a service that calls the HTTP endpoint and returns data
   constructor( protected dataService: DataService ) {}

   ngOnInit() {
       this.fetchData().subscribe();
   }

   private fetchData() {
       this.isLoading.next( true );
       return this.dataService.fetch().pipe(
           tap(data => {
               this.isLoading.next( false );
               this.data.next(data);
           })
       );
   }
}
```

When the service returns the data, It will be emitted to the `Subject`. That `Subject` is passed to the `ListView` component.

**list-view.component.ts**

```js
export class ListView {

   @Input() dataSet: Subject<any>;
   @Input() isLoading: BehaviourSubject<boolean>;
}
```

The problem comes when I render the data in **list-view.component.html**.

### Works Fine

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading |async">
   Loading...
</ng-container>
<ng-container>
   <div *ngFor="let data of dataSet |async">
      {{ data.id }}
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

### Not Working

```html
<!-- Loading shows and hides fine -->
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading |async">
   Loading...
</ng-container>

<!-- isLoading becomes false, But data not rendering -->
<ng-container *ngIf="!(isLoading |async)">
   <div *ngFor="let data of dataSet |async">
      {{ data.id }}
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

I checked the value of `isLoading` and `dataSet` by `subscribe`, The `isLoading` is becoming `false` when the service returns the data, and `dataSet` emits data fine **But** I am not sure, Why it's NOT rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Don't send your subject to your component.

Send the value of it.

```html
<list-view [dataSet]="data" [isLoading]="isLoading | async"></list-view>
```

Angular has built-in change detection on input changes, so rely on it, not only this reduces your code size, but it should also work better.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class ListView {

   @Input() dataSet: Subject<any>; // this should not be of type `Subject` because you are already passing the data from the BaseComponent. 
   @Input() isLoading: BehaviourSubject<boolean>;
}
```

Also, I would suggest you to pass `isLoading` flag as an Observable to your ListView component. currently, you're passing that as a BehaviourSubject.

Inside BaseComponent ts file

```
isLoading: BehaviourSubject<boolean> = new BehaviourSubject( false );
// add isLoading$
isLoading$: Observable<boolean> = isLoading.asObservable();
```

Send it like this to the child component

```
<list-view [dataSet]="data" [isLoading]="isLoading$ | async"></list-view>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the reason for the problem is that in this situation is about the order things happen, so as described:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!(isLoading |async)">
   <div *ngFor="let data of dataSet |async">
      {{ data.id }}
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

Both of these are effectively push variables, so when `dataSet` is given a value, if `isLoading` is false, that `*ngFor` is never rendered. If `isLoading` then becomes true, nothing will change until `dataSet` gets a *new* value.

I have a working solution, but I don't think it's necessarily good, I'm sure there are better or built-in ways to do this:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

   dataSet: BehaviourSubject<MyDataType> = new BehaviorSubject<MyDataType>();

   isLoading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject( true );
   
   constructor( protected dataService: DataService ) {}

   ngOnInit() {
       dataService.dataReceived.subscribe( db => {
           this.isLoading.next(false);
           setTimeout( () => {
               this.dataSet.next(db);
           }, 1);
       });
   }

}
```

Once `isLoading` is toggled this will now update the local `dataSet` property. The `setTimeout` forces it to trigger the update of `dataSet` after the `isLoading` has caused the container to be rendered, so now it can update the list.

Comment: it's unnecessary the "1" in setTimeout. When you use setTimeout -event if the time inverval is equal to 0 or not use-, Angular "make a new cycle" checking the values.

Comment: That is a useful tip, but in general I feel like it's a bad idea to get in the habit of calling `setTimeout` without a value - it may work in Angular but in other situations it could be unpredictable. Is there something Angular specific that forces it to wait out the current cycle before evaluating something?

Comment: there're several times you need "wait" Angular repaint. Imagine the typical input under a *ngIf and you want to make focus. (you need change the condition, wait Angular repaint and then make the focus). We can also use changeDetectorRef and [detechChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectchanges) Both methods force a new cycle. e.g. in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acmoek?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, create "on fly" an object in the way

```
<!--see the *ngIf is always true-->
<ng-container *ngIf="{loading:isLoading |async} as load">

  <!--here ask about "load.loading"-->
  <ng-container *ngIf="load.loading">
   Loading...
  </ng-container>

  <div *ngFor="let data of dataSet |async">
      {{ data.id }}
   </div>
</ng-container>
```